# get the format of a string date in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, date

I have a string date like 'Wednesday, May 15, 2013' when I Parse it o lost the original format, is there a way to know what was the original format date or get it before the final Parse?

Comment: In a word: no. If you care, also save the original string.

Comment: A given string may also fit into multiple date time formats!  For example, "11/11/11" fits into "M/d/yy" and "MM/dd/yy".

Comment: @user2089066 - Its not clear what your problem is exactly.  What was lost exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you'll lose the original format, if will now be a different object type with no care for its original format prior to parsing.

Your best option would be to store the pre-parse format prior to parsing as a different variable.

However if you simply wish to format the date in that original format, see [Farhad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16674221/370103).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for getting date in a fromat you wish.

```
String.Format("{0:D}", DateTime.Now); // Tuseday, May 21, 2013
```

Comment: True, but I think the point was "was it `2013-05-20` or `21/05/2013` or a full-out string".

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i understand. I was going to delete my answer, and then i saw that @Curt referenced my answer in his answer as a additional info.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` struct does not have a format, it stores all of those values on various properties. When you want to display it you specify which format to use.

Using a format specifier when displaying it will likely do what you want. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) mdsn article provides some basic information on format specifiers. The only way you can use the exact format you show there is if you know it ahead of time and have a format specifier for it. If you know you'll want to display strings in that format throughout the program it will be easy, if you get many different formats and want to decide how to display your dt at runtime it will be fairly complicated. I'm sure you could write some code to figure out what it is, but once the `DateTime` is created it will have no notion of what format the string used to create it was in.